# Asp.net asmx Web services performance

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, master-pages

I have created a asmx web service which is called from my Masterpage (at footer area) using jquery after some interval. I used this scenario to check whether any birthday wishes is pending or not if pending then a pop bar open in master page's footer are(I have implemented  JBar jquery plugin).

Now I want to know that for this any performance issue occurred or not. Or Please tel me any other idea to achieve this functionality.

I have thrown exception from the web service but it is not displayed in the ajax call.. please provide me solution

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonable approach and there shouldn't be any performance issues by doing this.

Comment: I have thrown exception from the web service but it is not displayed in the ajax call.. please provide me solution